# MultipartFormDataStreamProvider and appending to an existing file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cordova, asp.net-web-api

Hey Stackoverflow'ers,

I am using ASP.net WebApi to receive the upload from a Cordova application (which is send via a HTTP multi-part POST request).  The upload is "chunked" and as such, I need to create a file on first chunk then append each subsequent "chunk" to it.  Here is what I am working with so far:

```
public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path)
    { }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        var name = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers.ContentDisposition.FileName) ? headers.ContentDisposition.FileName : "NoName";
        return name.Replace("\"", string.Empty); //this is here because Chrome submits files in quotation marks which get treated as part of the filename and get escaped
    }
}
```

and in the controller...

```
    [Route("upload"), HttpGet, HttpPost]
    public void HandleUpload()
    {
        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/upload-temp");
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var streamProvider = new Libs.CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

            var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                });
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }
    }
```

I am assuming in CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider I would override GetStream somehow to accomplish the appending, but for the life of me can't get my head around it...

Does anyone have some insight into how to accomplish this?

Cheers :)

Comment: For clarity, is this a multipart `form-data` request? when you say chunked you mean their own custom implementation of chunks and not chunked transfer encoding..right?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure but I think so. http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer is a link for some documentation on Cordova's file transfer plugin.  The existing code above outputs a video file of 32 bytes which is what I assuming the last "chunk" of the upload.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the link...i believe this is chunked transfer encoding, in which case you should not need a custom multipart stream provider and you should be able to use the default one straight forward...

Comment: ok, so toss out my custom provider (which is only used currently to write out a custom file name)... I still am lost as to how to create then append the "chunks" to that file...

Comment: As per my understanding chunked transfer encoding is a lower level detail and at the application layer you can just keep reading the stream of bytes irrespective of the lower level details...in this case you can just use default multipart form-data stream provider and it takes care of reading the stream of bytes and creates a files at the provided root folder..

Answer (score 2):

This post was exactly the problem I was dealing with, and the trick is to override the **GetStream** method in your custom **MultipartFormDataStreamProvider**.  I based my solution on the source code of the System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider.

```
 public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers) {
        if (!headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.HasValue())
            return Stream.Null;

        if (parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parent");

        if (headers == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("headers");

        var fileName = this.GetLocalFileName(headers);

        if (!fileName.HasValue())
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

        var file = Path.Combine(this.RootPath, fileName);

        this.FileData.Add(new MultipartFileData(headers, file));

     // the key is appending a file as opposed to just creating it - the original ms implementation is:
      // return File.Create(file, this.BufferSize, FileOptions.Asynchronous)

       return new FileStream(file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, this.BufferSize, true);}
```